# ORM - Vaadin - JavaPersistence - Does not save the new entities

Tags: jpa, orm, persistence, eclipselink, vaadin

I am developing an application where I'm using Vaadin framework, the ORM JavaPersistence with Eclipselink and an Oracle database.

I have the following issue:
I've mapped all my logical model to the database with Annotations and if the DB has information, the mapping process brings me all the informacion. The problem appears when I want to save a new entity, with this I am trying to say that I create a new instance of a class and that class is not being saved in the database. The only way that I have to save that instance is to create a JPAContainer with the class type of the instance that I want to save, and call the method .AddEntity(instance).

I am new of this thing of object programming and ORMs. But up as I know, the ORM is useful tu save the memory data in the database.

This is my persistence.xml:

```
    org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider

</provider>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>
    false
</exclude-unlisted-classes>

 <properties> 

    <property name="javax.jbdc.platform" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.OraclePlatform" />


    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" /> 
     <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"/>
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="system" />
    <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="Windows706" />
    <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables"/>
```

Thanks in advance,
Regards!

Comment: How are you trying to persist your entity, and is it in a transaction?

Comment: The only way that I know where I can persist an entity is to use the entity JPAContainter and then, with the JPA call the method .AddEntity(AnIstance). Therefore I am looking for something more more automatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since EclipseLink its implementation of JPA you can save your entity in DB in a traditional way.

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("examplePersistenceUnit");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
try
{
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    YourEntity e = new YourEntity();
    e.setName("Chuck");
    e.setCity("Lisboa");
    em.persist(e);
    em.getTransaction().commit();
}
finally
{
    em.close();
    emf.close();
}
```

Good introduction to EclipseLink may be found [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html)